# Database Query on EL Contingency Data

Tags: oracle

I would like a couple of queries run on the EL Contingency table.

Find the earliest year of data and who has it (as in which entities)
Find the latest year of data and who has it (as in which entities)
Are there any years of EL Contingency that do not have matching years in PL_ESCALATION

Current script:

```
select a.accounting_entity_id,
       b.entity_short_name,
       min(a.fiscal_year) as lowest
  from dc.pl_el_contingency a
  left outer join emt.ae_entity b
    on (a.accounting_entity_id = b.accounting_entity_id)
 group by a.accounting_entity_id, b.entity_short_name;

select a.accounting_entity_id,
       b.entity_short_name,
       max(a.fiscal_year) as highest
  from dc.pl_el_contingency a
  left outer join emt.ae_entity b
    on (a.accounting_entity_id = b.accounting_entity_id)
 group by a.accounting_entity_id, b.entity_short_name;

SELECT e.accounting_entity_id
  FROM dc.pl_el_contingency e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dc.PL_ESCALATION s2
    ON (e.fiscal_year != s2.fiscal_year)
 WHERE s2.fiscal_year IS not NULL
 group by e.accounting_entity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your third query would return wrong results,Since you are checking only if the years are different.Kindly try the below

```
SELECT e.accounting_entity_id
FROM dc.pl_el_contingency e
where NOT EXISTS
              (select 1 from 
               dc.PL_ESCALATION s2
               where (e.fiscal_year = s2.fiscal_year)
               and  s2.fiscal_year IS not NULL)
 group by e.accounting_entity_id;
```